# Elastic Beanstalk is not seeing changes in DATABASES setting - Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Weird problem deploying Django on EB with Postgres.

Context: deploying a Django app on Elastic Beanstalk with postgresql 9.5. I've tried on two separate Windows 10  machines with the same results. Python 3.5 and Django 1.10.4.

Problem: when connecting to the database using the RDS environment variable, I accidentally look for "RDS_USER" rather than "RDS_USERNAME" in settings.py. This, naturally, throws a KeyError for "RDS_USER".

**However, if I change this to the proper value, commit the changes and re-deploy, eb does not pick up the changes.**

I still get the same KeyError for "RDS_USER" when trying to run a migration.

I can replicate this after modifying settings.py for postgres and adding some commands (venv, migrations)/packages (git, postgresql95-devel).

Has anyone else experienced this?

If I create a new instance and deploy initially with the proper variable name, it works fine.

**settings.py:**

```
if 'RDS_DB_NAME' in os.environ:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
            'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
            'PASSWORD' : os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
            'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
            'PORT':os.environ['RDS_PORT']
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'NAME': 'name',
            'USER':'user',
            'PASSWORD':'password',
            'HOST':'localhost',
            'PORT':''
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you deploying using the console or awscli?

Answer (score 1):

I use awscli as well and my DB settings look just like yours and they work fine. Did you try to create a new EB instance and see if that works?

Comment: That's what I've done before and it works without issue. Just wondering why this is happening/if there is a way to avoid switching out to a new instance